# Where is the Network Block Device format described?

Tags: networking, network-protocols, network-block-device

What is the format of [network block device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_block_device) protocol? It is [stated](http://wiki.wireshark.org/NBD) that it is simple, but I can't find any RFC or similar things that describes what client and server should send.

Comment: Interesting problem. Never thought about a `network block device` before. nice :)

Answer (score 4):

Found myself. Looks like here is the document: https://github.com/yoe/nbd/blob/master/doc/proto.md . Not so simple...

Additionally there is simple Python-based server: http://lists.canonical.org/pipermail/kragen-hacks/2004-May/000397.html

Answer (score 0):

Further adding to it, the exact communication format of NBD client and NBD server can be briefly described as following:

> **Client**:
> The client component of NBD configures a local block device as /dev/nbdX. Requests submitted to this device are sent through a socket to the server side implemented in userspace. The client can be configured with a userspace utility called [nbd-client](https://github.com/NetworkBlockDevice/nbd/blob/master/nbd-client.c) [1].

> **Server**:
> Server implements userspace handlers for requests sent by the client.
> NBD can use Unix-domain sockets instead of network sockets to eliminate the
> overhead of connection management. Furthermore, a multi-connect connection
> can be used to increase performance due to introduced parallelism in the
> server part [1]. High-performance server implementations with plugin support
> exist, such as [nbdkit](https://gitlab.com/nbdkit/nbdkit) or [nbd-server](https://github.com/NetworkBlockDevice/nbd/blob/master/nbd-server.c).

In addition to the earlier useful answer that mentions [proto.md](https://github.com/NetworkBlockDevice/nbd/blob/master/doc/proto.md) below are some more useful resources that can help to understand in more detail the functions of client and server.

**References and Resources**:

[1] [BUSE: Block Device in Userspace](https://dspace.cuni.cz/bitstream/handle/20.500.11956/148791/120397658.pdf)

[2] [The Network Block Device-Linux Journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3778)

[3] [BDUS: implementing block devices in user space](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3456727.3463768)